# How to remove row that contains the same element in data frame pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very big data frame `[541909 rows x 8 columns]`. This is how it looks:

```
       InvoiceNo StockCode                          Description  Quantity      InvoiceDate  UnitPrice  CustomerID         Country
0         536365    85123A   WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER         6   12/1/2010 8:26       2.55     17850.0  United Kingdom
1         536365     71053                  WHITE METAL LANTERN         6   12/1/2010 8:26       3.39     17850.0  United Kingdom
2         536365    84406B       CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER         8   12/1/2010 8:26       2.75     17850.0  United Kingdom
3         536365    84029G  KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE         6   12/1/2010 8:26       3.39     17850.0  United Kingdom
4         536365    84029E       RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.         6   12/1/2010 8:26       3.39     17850.0  United Kingdom
...          ...       ...                                  ...       ...              ...        ...         ...             ...
541904    581587     22613          PACK OF 20 SPACEBOY NAPKINS        12  12/9/2011 12:50       0.85     12680.0          France
541905    581587     22899         CHILDREN'S APRON DOLLY GIRL          6  12/9/2011 12:50       2.10     12680.0          France
541906    581587     23254        CHILDRENS CUTLERY DOLLY GIRL          4  12/9/2011 12:50       4.15     12680.0          France
541907    581587     23255      CHILDRENS CUTLERY CIRCUS PARADE         4  12/9/2011 12:50       4.15     12680.0          France
541908    581587     22138        BAKING SET 9 PIECE RETROSPOT          3  12/9/2011 12:50       4.95     12680.0          France
```

I want to delete all the InvoiceNo that repeats on each row and keep only one. For instance, the first 5 rows have the same InvoiceNo so I only want to keep one of those rows.

I tried to do it with a for loop however it takes forever as the dataset is very big. Is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: As I see rows are different. What would be the logic of removing duplicate InvoiceNo? Keep smallest index, max values, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates` (see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)) as suggested by @Netim

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

duplicates = np.random.randint(0, 10, 100)
values = np.arange(0, 100)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dupl': duplicates,
    'vals': values
})
```

then you can do

```
df.drop_duplicates(
    subset='dupl', keep='first',
    ignore_index=True
)
```

or

```
df.drop_duplicates(
    subset='dupl', keep='last',
    ignore_index=True
)
```

but, as @Alex said, you have to decide which duplicate you want to keep.